# Node+MongoDB efficient query based on average

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance

I have a complicated (or not so much) problem and need an advice. I need to store ~20K documents, each with ~400 sub-documents. Have to get documents, which sub-documents have one of the properties greather or lesser from average by x percentage. How to do it in proper (efficient) way? I don't need whole snipped to copy - just, please, point me the way and i will handle the rest myself.

EDIT: Main documents are companies and sub-documents are their stock market data. Each sub-document represents one day of company's historical stock market ratings. It looks like this:

```
{  
    name,  
    stockSymbol,  
    tickets: [{  
        date,  
        low,  
        high,  
        close,  
        open  
    }, {  
    ...  
    }  
    ...]  
}
```

Request parameters are: startDate, endDate, times, percent.

What i need to do is fetch companies where in tickets between "startDate" and "endDate" "low" or "high" parameters are lower or higher (accordingly) from "close" average by "percent" percenteges in that period "times" times.

I have try numbers of solutions, including extracting sub-documents to another collection, but number of data is overwhelming (20k companies and 365 sub-documents each for one-year history).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports querying embedded documents(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/). It does better in my use case (~200 subdocuments).

But I would suggest to keep an eye on the ~400. If the sub-documents are keep growing then It will be end up with other performance issues.

The more sub-documents will make your documents heavier and will be challenging to perform `find` operations. The heavier documents will take more CPU and Disk utilization. It may also lead to `unbounded array` issues.

Comment: You're answer was very helpful, but it's not quite what i need. I have edited first post to deliver more details.